# In Bash, grep for a line and print that line in a file but with more information

Tags: bash, grep, echo

In bash, I am using the `grep` command to print the result to a file:

```
  grep "4 CA   1" CVOLOPTs*SYMREMO.out | grep "11 O    0 0 0" >> data.dat
```

Which prints the following in the `data.dat` file:

```
 4 CA   1     2.3311     4.4052   11 O    0 0 0
```

I would like to make the `data.dat` look like the following:

```
 252   4 CA   1     2.3311     4.4052   11 O    0 0 0
```

I have tried something like:

```
grep "4 CA   1" CVOLOPTs*SYMREMO.out | grep "11 O    0 0 0" >> echo "252" data.dat
```

But does not work.

I would appreciate if you could help me please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An additional pipe with `awk` could do the trick:

```
grep "4 CA   1" CVOLOPTs*SYMREMO.out | grep "11 O    0 0 0" | awk ´{print "252",$0}´ >> data.dat
```

the whole thing can be done with a single `awk`:

```
awk ´/4 CA   1/ && /11 O    0 0 0/ {print "252",$0}' CVOLOPTs*SYMREMO.out >> data.dat
```

`$0` is the entire current line. In this situation, the line selected by the 2 regex.

`awk` reads each line one by one.

Regex stands for regular expression. With `awk` they are enclosed into `/`:  e.g. `/4 CA   1/`

`/4 CA   1/ && /11 O    0 0 0/` is an expression: it is true when the line being read matches both the first regex `and` (`&&`) the second regex. In this situation there are just strings; see 
[9. Regular Expressions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html) from the Open Group Base Specifications Issue 6.

Comment: Thanks! But it must be `'{print "252",$0}'` instead in the first command. And, the second command should be `'/4 CA   1/ && /11 O    0 0 0/ {print "252",$0}'` instead (I think). But thank you very much! :)

Comment: OK, thank you. I just copy-pasted  the strings options from `grep`s.

Comment: What does the `$0$` stands for?

Comment: $0 is the entire current line. In this situation, the line selected by the 2 regex.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by the `2 regex` ? I would appreciate if you could expand a bit on your answer, I am learning... Thanks a lot ! +1!

Comment: @DavidC. the answer had been updated. In your situation, the regex are simple strings but it is possible to use patterns that could match several strings.

Comment: @DavidC. a link to regex had been inserted in the answer.

Comment: Thanks  a lot for your for your explanation! +1 for your comment. These days I've been learning awk intensively... please click on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37104901/in-awk-search-for-some-certain-columns-of-a-curent-line to see my progress ( I believe... see the large script I made) but unfortunately a new stuck... Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You may not need to use `grep` as you could achieve the desired output
with this `awk` one-liner :

```
awk '/4 CA   1/ && /11 O    0 0 0/{printf "252\t%s\n",$0}' CVOLOPTs*SYMREMO.out >> data.dat
```

I have put a tab after 252 which might change to one or more whitespaces

Comment: Thank you very much! :) (I'm afraid this works in a way I cannot give you a +1 since I've got less than 15 reputation...)