# In awk, search for some certain columns of a curent line

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file named `c_FROM_V_273_008245_50_neighbours_SYMREMO.out` that looks like:

```
NEIGHBORS OF THE NON-EQUIVALENT ATOMS

N = NUMBER OF NEIGHBORS AT DISTANCE R
ATOM  N     R/ANG      R/AU   NEIGHBORS (ATOM LABELS AND CELL INDICES)
1 CA   1     2.4055     4.5458    7 O    0 0 0
1 CA   1     2.4058     4.5463   10 O    0-1 0
1 CA   1     2.4356     4.6026   14 O    0 0 0
.
.
.
```

If I wanted to search for the distance in `R/ANG` for `1 CA  7 O`, it would be `2.4055`

I have created this script: **search_for_distance.awk**:

```
 {if ($0 ~ "NEIGHBORS OF THE NON-EQUIVALENT ATOMS") {FLAG=1}};
 # If the current line of the file begins with that string, we asign it a FLAG=1

    {if (FLAG==1)
            {if ($0 ~ "^   1 CA"){LINE=$0;
            exit}
            }
    };
    # Here I am searching for "1 CA" on each line

 END{VOL=FILENAME;
 # The filename is: "c_FROM_V_273_008245_50_neighbours_SYMREMO.out"
 # My intention is to end up with a new file with 2 columns:
 # "volume" and "distance". 
 # Notice that the filename contains the volume: 273.008245

 gsub("^.*_V_","",VOL);
 gsub("_",".",VOL);
 gsub(".50.neighbours.SYMREMO.out"," ",VOL);
 # Some substitutions to make "c_FROM_V_273_008245_50_neighbours_SYMREMO.out" 
 # to be "273.008245"

 # Up to now the output of running: 
 # search_for_distance.awk -f c_FROM_V_273_008245_50_neighbours_SYMREMO.out
 # is the following:

 # 273.008245     1 CA   1     2.4055     4.5458    7 O    0 0 0

 # So, I need to take LINE and only extract column "4".
 # This is done by a "split" command:

 {split(LINE,array," ")}   

 print VOL,array[4]}
```

the output of running: 
`search_for_distance.awk -f c_FROM_V_273_008245_50_neighbours_SYMREMO.out`
is the following:

```
 273.008245  2.4055
```

Notice that the script is printing the 1st appearance of `1 CA`, which happens to be `1 CA  7O`, which is what I wanted.

But now I need to run this for searching the first appearence many distances...

I would like to search for the first appearance of the `1 CA` `14 O` distance.
I would only have to modify the first bit of the code where I am searching from the beginning of the line to `1 CA`:

```
 {if ($0 ~ "NEIGHBORS OF THE NON-EQUIVALENT ATOMS") {FLAG=1}};
 # If the current line begins with that string, we asign it a FLAG=1

    {if (FLAG==1)
            {if ($0 ~ "^   1 CA"){LINE=$0;
            exit}
            }
    };
```

How could I introduce an order to search for `1 CA` `14 O`?

Something like

```
    {if (FLAG==1)
            {if ($0 ~ "/1 CA   && /14 O"){LINE=$0;
            exit}
            }
    };
```

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: You'll either need a more complex regex or (what I suggest), have the line starting pattern be `$1 == 1 && $2 == "CA" && $6==14 && $7==0 && flag == 1` I think you can take it from there

Comment: @mpez0 : Where should I put this command in the **search_for_distance.awk** script ? Thanks

Comment: It's a line pattern match; it goes before the action for the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to search for the distance in R/ANG for 1 CA  7 O, which in this case is 2.4055

```
$ awk '$1==1 && $2=="CA" && $6==7 && $7=="O" {print $4}' file
2.4055
```

To find R/Ang for 1 CA 14 O:

```
$ awk '$1==1 && $2=="CA" && $6==14 && $7=="O" {print $4}' file
2.4356
```

#### How it works

- `$1==1 && $2=="CA" && $6==7 && $8==0`

  This selects lines for which the four stated conditions are true.
- `print $4`

  For the selected lines, this prints the fourth field.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately this is not what I asked.... What I asked is at the end of the question. Thanks again

Comment: @DavidC. Change 7 to 14, it would do.

Comment: @John1024 If I were to find `1 CA 7O`, or `1 CA 14O` it has to be `$8=="O"` instead of `$8==0` in your command. And, the `awk '$1==1 && $2=="CA" && $6==7 && $8=="O" {print $4}' file` does not work, why?

Comment: @DavidC. I have updated the answer to look for the capital-letter "O" in the seventh column and provide solutions for both the cases of 7 and for 14.